# Issue affection only users on Android 11 version

Tags: android, motorola, android-11

My app has about 20k daily active users and there is a fatal crash affecting only android 11 users that I'm not able to identify the root cause.

the stack trace is

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.android.server.wm.TaskDisplayArea.getDisplayId()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2054)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7755)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

100% affected users are android 11 Motorola devices [3 different Motorola models]
and 100% of the times app is in the background

the stack trace shows that is something related to showing an image on the screen but the error happens in many different situations that I'm aware of a common code [of mine] that could be the cause

does anyone face this issue?
is there any Motorola-related issue known that could be the cause?
is there any way to better debug it and maybe identify the root cause?

Comment: Hi! Did you find some solution? I'm getting this exception and it's impossible to find the reason

Comment: @pablobaldez does it happen only for motorola phones also?

Comment: yes. Exact same situation. Moto G and Moto G power devices, android 11 and 97% of the cases happening when the app are in background

Comment: Did you find some solution? I need fix it :(